# wpf listview item animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need some advice. Would anyone know how to make this ListView animation in wpf. I need the ListView item animation to run symmetrically see gif 1.
[image: gif 1]

But the problem is that the ListView can't scroll and the items are generally displaced, as the setting for VirtualizingStackPanel is HorizontalAlignment="Center" and for ListView I have set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False".

So, how can I modify the code so that the animation of the items in the ListView is symmetrical while preserving the scrolling.

my current code looks like this:

```
<ListView
      x:Name="ListView1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <VirtualizingStackPanel
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  CacheLength="10,10"
                  CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"
                  IsItemsHost="True"
                  IsVirtualizing="True"
                  Orientation="Horizontal"
                  ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                  VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
              </VirtualizingStackPanel>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ListViewItem>
          <Button
              Width="100"
              Height="120"
              Margin="3"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              FontSize="18"
              FontWeight="Bold"
              Foreground="MediumPurple"
              MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
              MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" />
      </ListViewItem>

      <!--  more items  -->

  </ListView>
```

```
    private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = sender as Button;
        var WidthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 130, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        var HeightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 150, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };

        button.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, WidthAnimation);
        button.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, HeightAnimation);
    }

    private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = sender as Button;
        var WidthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 100, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        var HeightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 120, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };

        button.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, WidthAnimation);
        button.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, HeightAnimation);
    }
```

Comment: You may want to animate a ScaleTransfom in the RenderTransform of the Button. This won't affect layout. Note that such animations could be declared in XAML. You don't need the event handler code.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's your question here, cause your code works pretty much the same as it looks on the gif (except of course for the `Button` styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add extra horizontal margin to ItemsPanel and decrease it when a Button is enlarged to compensate the increased width.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                    IsVirtualizing="True"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                    Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                    Loaded="ItemsPanel_Loaded"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Button Width="100"
                                Height="120"
                                Margin="3"
                                FontSize="18"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Foreground="MediumPurple"
                                MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
                                MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

```cs
private Panel? _panel;

private void ItemsPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _panel = sender as Panel;
}

private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        var widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = 130, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        button.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
    }
    if (_panel is not null)
    {
        var marginAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation { To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        _panel.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, marginAnimation);
    }
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        var widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = 100, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        button.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
    }
    if (_panel is not null)
    {
        var marginAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation { To = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0), Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
        _panel.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, marginAnimation);
    }
}
```

The height animation is omitted for brevity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for.